# The CSS changes are not reflecting in the app using "tns preview"

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am new to nativescript! and I was following the "Getting Started" video course from nativescript's website. I was not able see the css change when I ran "tns preview" command. I tried with inline css and it works. But the css changes do not reflect when they are defined in the css files.

In the global css file, I wrote the following CSS:

```
@import url("~/platform.css");

Page {
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 25;
}

TextField {
    padding: 10;
    font-size: 13;
}
```

Some observations:

1. When I comment out the import, then only the TextField css are applied and not the Page. (I was trying to import the css from platform.ios.css file)
2. I think, it is not able to find platform.css file as this file is not generated in the "platforms" folder.

**Note**: I am not using emulator as I do not have a mac and "tns run ios" won't run in windows, so I have to use my iPhone to preview the app.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: I doubt platform specific files work with preview. Platform specific files work only when you really compile them, with `tns run | build`.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a couple of assumptions here to answer your question:
1. You are using NativeScript Core
2. You have a file named `platform.ios.css` in the `/app` folder along with the `app.css` file (your global css file)

Please change your import statement in `app.css` to look like this:

```
@import 'platform.css';
```

Just an opinionated note: I also suggest trying this on a local Android emulator since you are on Windows. The preview app is great, but it will have quite a few limits once you dig deeper and having a local emulator will get you further.

Comment: Hey Alex! I tried the change you suggested but unfortunately it did not work. To be more precise, I am currently watching your "NativeScript with Angular Getting Started tutorial" and I am stuck at this point - https://courses.nativescripting.com/courses/169856/lectures/2573646

Comment: Hey Saif. You mentioned you got this working (on Twitter). Can you comment, and mark this as resolved on not - it may help others who find this tread. Thanks.